# Prevent Double Row Section UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I am navigating to a new ViewController (B) when a user selects a "row" in a UITableView on ViewController (A).

If I quickly press back from B before B has finished loading and then immediatly try and select another row **sometimes** the app seems to get stuck. Then it  catches up processing multiple "Row Selections". I want to stop selection after the first one.

I know this has been asked before and the suggestion is UserInteractionEnabled = false.

However that doesn't seem to work and more importantly I cannot see a good enough place to switch UserInteractionEnabled back on when the user navigates back to the View with the table.

How do other people solve this?

I am using Xamarin iOS but I am sure it is not a problem specific to Xamarin

Comment: I think on the first click you must start to navigate to next screen then how the user can click twice. Is there any lag or wait time in navigating next screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're quite right, one of the ways to prevent that method from firing more than once is to disable the tables user interaction.

However as to how do you re-enable it. That can be done just after the method has pushed your viewcontroller onto your navigation stack:

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    if (tableView.CellAt(indexPath).GetType() == typeof(YourCell)) // For multiple cell types
    {

            // Disable Interaction on click
            tableView.UserInteractionEnabled = false;

            // Animate selection
            tableView.CellAt(indexPath).SetHighlighted(true, true);

            // Load our new viewcontroller

            yourNewView myview = AppDelegate.ADSelf.GlobalNavigationController.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController(nameof(yourNewView)) as yourNewView;
            AppDelegate.ADSelf.GlobalTabBarController.ShowViewController(myview);

            // Enable Interaction on click
            tableView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

That really is one of the better solutions if you ask me. You can take it one step further, and ensure that the new view isn't already on the navigation stack, and return if it is. Like so:

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    if (tableView.CellAt(indexPath).GetType() == typeof(YourCell)) // For multiple cell types
    {
            // Disable Interaction on click
            tableView.UserInteractionEnabled = false;

            // Animate selection
            tableView.CellAt(indexPath).SetHighlighted(true, true);

            // Load our new viewcontroller
            yourNewView myview = AppDelegate.ADSelf.GlobalNavigationController.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController(nameof(yourNewView)) as yourNewView;

            // Check if it already exists on our stack

            if(AppDelegate.ADSelf.GlobalNavigationController.TopViewController.GetType() == typeof(myview)
            {
                // Enable Interaction on click
                tableView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;

                return;
            }

            AppDelegate.ADSelf.GlobalTabBarController.ShowViewController(myview);

            // Enable Interaction on click
            tableView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen the "Check if it already exists on our stack" approach before and I do agree however I have to run this code in the UITableViewSource and the code to actualty Show the view controller is abstracted away in a "navigation service".

Comment: See I keep a static reference to that in my app delegate class where I then have a public variable that my UITabBarController gets assigned to when it's instantiated. . However you could pass through your parent views navigation controller as a parameter to your tables source &#128077;